# ofstream::write fails in the middle when writing large binary files

Tags: c++, ofstream

During runtime my program creates and writes two large binary files simutaneously to the disk. File A is about 240GB, file B is about 480GB. The two files are maintained by two `ofstream` objects, and the write opertations are performed with the member funcion `write` in a loop.

Now the problem is: The write file operation fails everytime the whole write file procedure reaches 63~64%. The first time it failed on file A, and the second time it failed on file B.

During the program runs these days, the power supply of my building happens to be under upgrade. By a strange coincidence, every time the program failed, the electrician happened to be cutting and resuming the power supply of the central air-conditioner and some offices. Therefore, I really wonder whether the write file failures were caused by unstable power supply.

I'm sure that the failure is not caused by file size limit, because I've tried to write a single 700GB file using the same method without any problem.

Is there any way to find out the detailed reason? I feel that the flags (`badbit`, `eofbit` and `failbit`) of `ofstream` don't provide too much information. Now I'm trying to use `errno` and `strerror` to get the detailed error message. However, I see that a possible value of `errno` is `EIO`, which measn "I/O error", which again provides no useful information.

Is there anyone who encountered this situation before?

By the way, the program runs without error when the sizes of file A and file B are small.

PS: This time the program fails at 55%, and the errno value is EINVAL: Invalid argument. Very strange.

Comment: have you tried to write just the 63~64% subset of the file?

Comment: @moooeeeep: But what it just happens now is, it just write the 63~64% subset of the two files. I can see that the 63~64% subset is successfully written because I saw the two files were growing bigger and bigger when the program rans.

Comment: Perhaps a S.M.A.R.T. utility can give some clues.

Comment: @n.m.: Thanks. You remind me to setup some monitoring utilities while running the program. I'll try it.

Comment: I have submitted a bug to [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/739637/ofstream-write-succeeds-when-writing-a-huge-file-but-fails-when-writing-two-smaller-files#details)

Comment: Seems that the cause is [A heavily fragmented file in an NTFS volume may not grow beyond a certain size](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;967351)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed, the cause is indeed a bug of NTFS: [A heavily fragmented file in an NTFS volume may not grow beyond a certain size](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;967351). This means that CreateFile and WriteFile cannot fundamentally solve the problem, either.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I've solved the problem with Win32 API: CreateFile and WriteFile.